# What is the need of a temporary register for Arithmetic operations in 8085 microprocessor?

Tags: cpu-registers, microprocessors, accumulator, alu, 8085

I know the two inputs of `ALU` are `accumulator` and the `temporary` register.I was bit curious that why we store intermediate result in a temporary register and why not the data bus is directly connected to the `ALU`.What is the need of that temporary register in the `8085` microprocessor ?

Answer (score 0):

One of the uses of a temporary register is to stabilize the timing of the data flow.

Consider the example you hint at in your question: An ALU operation with the Accumulator and a memory operand.

Yes, the memory operand is read from memory. So why not feed this directly into the ALU? 
One possible answer is timing.

The data being read from memory is only valid at the end of the bus cycle. This data goes away when the bus cycle ends. This means that the data is only known to be valid for a very brief period of time.

In all likelihood, too short a period of time to propagate through the ALU and be stored in the Accumulator.

However, more than enough time to simply be stored directly into a temporary register. The ALU then has two stable inputs: The Accumulator and the Temporary register.

In effect, the temporary register holds the result of the memory operation for use by the ALU in the next processor cycle.